# Referencing JavaScript file from a different assembly in a Blazor project

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, blazor

I have a Razor Class Library project in which I want to add a couple of custom components that use JavaScript interops. The interops work fine when I call functions that already exist in the Window object.
This, for example, works fine:

```
JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Hello world");
```

However when the functions I need are not native to the Window object, i.e. they are declared in a distinct interops.js file, I need to add a `<script>` tag referencing the said file in the page HTML. What is the path to that file since it resides in a different assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this.

### Consume static assets from a referenced RCL

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consume-content-from-a-referenced-rcl)

> The files included in the wwwroot folder of the RCL are exposed to either the RCL or the consuming app under the prefix _content/{LIBRARY NAME}/. For example, a library named Razor.Class.Lib results in a path to static content at _content/Razor.Class.Lib/. When producing a NuGet package and the assembly name isn't the same as the package ID, use the package ID for {LIBRARY NAME}.

## Read embedded asset contents using Reflection

This approach lets you execute Javascript code directly without need to include files in the HTML with `<script>`.

First create helper method to retrieve embedded javascript file contents:

```cs
public static string GetEmbeddedJSInteropCode(Assembly assembly, string path)
{
    using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```cs
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", GetEmbeddedJSInteropCode(typeof(SomeRCLType).Assembly, "SomeRCL.SomeFolder.Init.js"));
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("someRCLFunction", "Foobar");
```

Answer (score 2):

When the Razor Class Assembly is referenced in a Blazor Web Assembly project, the content of the Razor `wwwroot/` folder is copied in the Blazor `_content/*namespace*/` folder. So the solution is to move the .js file in the wwwroot/ and reference it in the script tag like this:

```
<script src="_content/*assembly_name*/file.js"></script>
```